# WEB3JS Transaction faling

Tags: web3js, polygon

I want to interact with my smart contract via WEB3JS. Currently I am facing the issue that insted of minting tokens it fails.

Example on the block explorer: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x5c51ea9807abb2b99e20ca6905d4039f7f8f9ccd4c0945b17f0b4b1623273f5f

This is the current code:

```
        //Adding QuickNodeAPI
        var web3 = new Web3('https://restless-warmhearted-tent.matic-testnet.discover.quiknode.pro/XXXXXXXXX/%27);

        // Setting wallet variables
        const privateKey = 'XXXXXXX';
        var WalletID = '0xc7deAF4E3C5900a725c1d5D076859c9606395620';
        web3.eth.accounts.wallet.add(privateKey);

        // Use the web3 instance to create the contract instance
        const Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(<?php echo $row['ABI']; ?>, '<?php echo $row['ContractAdres']; ?>')

        // Creating the transaction
        const tx = {
          gasLimit: 500000, // Use the minimum gas limit
          gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('20', 'gwei'), // Set the gas price to 20 gwei
          nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(WalletID),
          data: Contract.methods.mint('0xc7deAF4E3C5900a725c1d5D076859c9606395620', web3.utils.toWei('3', 'ether')).encodeABI(),
        };

        //Signing transaction and error handeling
        web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey).then(signed => {
          web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction).on('transactionHash', txHash => {
            web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash).then(receipt => {
              if (receipt) {
                console.log('Transaction confirmed')
              } else {
                console.log('Transaction pending')
              }
            });
          });
        })
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the address of the contract (the destination) to your transaction.

probably here

```
      const tx = {
          to: 'the-address-of-the-contract'
          gasLimit: 500000, // Use the minimum gas limit
          gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei('20', 'gwei'), // Set the gas price to 20 gwei
          nonce: web3.eth.getTransactionCount(WalletID),
          data: Contract.methods.mint('0xc7deAF4E3C5900a725c1d5D076859c9606395620', web3.utils.toWei('3', 'ether')).encodeABI(),
        };
```

Without the correct `to` the evm thinks you are trying to create a contract. You can see in Polygon scanner it says "Contract 0x022dae72497c5e5f4476e6caa3123ae48a52a0e0 Created" and failed
[image]

Comment: Oh man it worked! You are a hero!